# AndroidDrawable - How do I set the default start/stop frames?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I am trying to use [AndroidDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) for an animation in a loop (i.e. play the images continuously). But the problem that is bugging me is that I can not find an *elegant* way to set a default start/stop image for the animation.

Example: Imagine that I have five images viz.: 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' and 'E'.

```
 <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/A" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/B" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/C" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/D" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/E" android:duration="200" />
 </animation-list>
```

When I start the animation, it evidently starts with the image 'A' and finishes at an image corresponding to whenever the animation stops (i.e. whenever the method `Stop()` is executed)

My question therefore is: "How do I set the default start/stop frames?".

For now, I use the following solution which works but is not too *elegant*. I am sure that there is a better solution :)

My solution:

- To begin the animation with image 'C', I move the item to the top of the animation-list.
- To end the animation with image 'C', I call the method `Stop()` method (This stops the animation at a random image). I then call the method `Start()` which starts the animation and the first image 'C' is shown. I call method `Stop()` immediately after which makes sure that the animation stops at image 'C'.

Comment: How do you *move the item to the top of the animation-list*?

Comment: Well that could be done programmatically too I guess, but for now I have tested it moving manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an *elegant* way to do it, just set the background to @drawable/C when the animation stops